# Java Array, method cannot find symbol

Tags: java, arrays, oop, methods

I have something like thi

```
//constructors

public IntBag()   {
  myBag = new Integer[500];
}

public boolean contains( int aNumber)   {
  if ( bag[aNumber] == null )
    return false;
  else
    return true;    }

public int size()   {
 int num;    
num= 0; //Number of filled slot    

for( int j = 0; j < myBag.length; j++) {   
 if ( myBag.contains(j) )
    num++;     }    
return num;    }
```

I get an error 
Error: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method contains(int)
  location: variable bag of type java.lang.Integer[]

How can I solve this?

Comment: I have written that method

Comment: `bag` is an array of `Integer`s. You could use `Arrays.asList( bag ).contains( i )`

Comment: Why it is not working in this way

Comment: You could just use an array list `ArrayList<Integer>`

Comment: *"Why it is not working in this way "* - because arrays have no method called `contains`.

Comment: What do you think `if ( bag.contains(i) )` does?

Comment: It supposed to run the method that I have written

Comment: What makes you think that it's supposed to do that?

Comment: they are in the same class and I am calling a contains method

Comment: And??? That's not how Java works. Are you just guessing the syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're trying to use *your method*, you don't call it on the array, you pass values  *to it*

```
if ( contains(i) )
```

For clarity, you're calling a method of the instance of `IntBag`, not an integer array (which has no contains method)

You can achieve the same by

```
if ( this.contains(i) )
```

Note: you'll want to catch out of bounds exception in that method